# Sounds firmware installation has failed for internal reason

Tags: installation, stm32, firmware, stm32f0, peripherals

I am using OpenSTM Workbench to try and program an STM32F0 MCU. I am using Eclipse (with OpenSTM extension) on Windows 10. I keep getting the following error when I try to install the peripheral library for my variant when creating a project:

> Sounds firmware installation has failed for internal reason
> Error code = ERROR_DOWNLOAD_TASK_START_ISSUE

Full screenshot of the error:

[image: error message]

I have tried downloading the zip of the peripheral library and putting it in the firmware directory and this did not work. For some reason the other firmware (Hardware Abstraction Layer) installed itself fine. I tried copying the format it uses in folder, with both the zip and extracted files but to no avail.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Note that this problem is also discussed on the OpenSTM32 Community in [this](https://www.openstm32.org/forumthread8075) and [this](https://www.openstm32.org/forumthread8122) topic.

Comment: [Here](https://www.openstm32.org/forumthread5300)'s a slightly different but related issue discussed (same error message, different error code). Further down the thread your ERROR_DOWNLOAD_TASK_START_ISSUE error is discussed as well (not mentioned in text but in screenshot only, see post by ibisek on 2020-01-04 15:00). A possible work-around for the problem is discussed below it.